# How to write a copy constructor?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

I am having some trouble figuring out how to write my copy constructor...

This is my constructor:

```
public:
Person(const char * aName, const char * userID, const char * domain, Date aDate) {
//This constructor should create heap objects

    name = new char[strlen(aName) + 1]; 
    strcpy (name, aName);
    emailAddress = new EmailAddress(userID, domain); 
    birthday = new Date(aDate); 

    cout << "\nPerson(...) CREATING: ";
    printOn(cout);
}
```

This is what I am trying to do for my copy constructor:

```
Person(const Person & p){
    name = new char[strlen(p.name)+1];
    strcpy(name, p.name);
    emailAddress = new EmailAddress(*p.emailAddress);
    birthday = new Date(*p.date);

    cout << "\nPerson(const Person &) CREATING: ";
    printOn(cout);
}
```

I am unsure of what to pass in for my new Date and new EmailAddress in my copy constructor, what I am doing right now is not working at all!

This is my assignment operator for good measure (I don't know what to pass in for date and emailAddress again here...):

```
Person & operator=(const Person & p) {
        if(&p != this) {
           delete [] name;
           delete emailAddress;
           delete birthday;
           name = new char[strlen(p.name) + 1];
           strcpy (name, p.name);
               emailAddress = new EmailAddress();
               birthday = new Date();
        }
        return *this;
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:

Date definition

```
class Date{ //this class is complete
//This class represents a date

public:
      Date(int aDay, int aMonth, int aYear) : day(aDay), month(aMonth), year(aYear) {} 
      Date(const Date & aDate) :  day(aDate.day), month(aDate.month), year(aDate.year)     {};
      void printOn(ostream & out) const {out << day <<"/" << month << "/" << year;}
```

Comment: Unless you need custom logic in the copy constructor, you don't. The runtime does it for you

Comment: I'm really just trying to learn how to write my own, but I'm stuck on how to do so

Comment: Can we see the definition for your `Date` type?

Comment: Hmm. Can we also see the class definition for Person? (What are the types of `name`, `emailAddress`, `birthday`?) Also, when you say, “I am unsure of what to pass in for my new Date and new EmailAddress in my copy constructor, what I am doing right now is not working at all!” — what do you mean? what error do you get?

Comment: I get an access violation error.  name is of char array, emailAddress is of type EmailAddress, and birthday is of type Date.

I posted the constructor for Person at the top of my question, hopefully that helps clarify things?

Comment: Why do you have `*p` in your copy constructor for the `date` and `emailAddress`? Shouldn't it just be `p.date` (or `p.birthdate`) and `p.emailAddress` ?

Comment: @Sarah: I'd like to see the class definition itself, actually. Currently, I'm assuming that `birthday` is a `Date *` and a member, but then it should work when you call `Date(*p.birthday)`. Since something is wrong, I'm poking around for the problem.

Comment: The first thing I would do is remove the need to call `new`.  Unless you have a requirement that forces you to call `new` (subclasses etc), don't do it.  Use std::string for strings.  STL containers for lists, arrays, maps, etc. and let the library code deal with `new`.  Once `new` is gone, your constructors become adapters between the initializer lists and `operator=`

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to break JimR's comment out into an answer, as it is good advice: Use C++ types, not C types, if possible. Also, avoid pointers if possible.

#### Using C++ Types

For example, your class, as best we can see it, looks like this:

```
class Person {
    char *name;
    Email *emailAddress;
    Date *birthday;
};
```

If `Date` and `Email` are lightweight enough (and they should be), keep them as values in the object itself; also, make `name` a `std::string`:

```
class Person {
    std::string name;
    Email emailAddress;
    Date birthday;
};
```

Your constructor becomes exceedingly trivial:

```
Person::Person(const std::string &aName, const std::string &userID, const std::string &domain, Date aDate) :
    name(aName),
    emailAddress(userID, domain),
    birthday(aDate)
{ }
```

Even better, the default copy constructor that C++ makes for you will now just work. So will the destructor, *and* the assignment operator. For free. *Even better*, all of these are now exception-safe: if, for whatever reason an exception gets raised, everything will get cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working - thank you everyone for helping me!  I had to pass in *p.emailAddress, and *p.birthday

```
Person(const Person & p){
    name = new char[strlen(p.name)+1];
    strcpy(name, p.name);
    emailAddress = new EmailAddress(*p.emailAddress);
    birthday = new Date(*p.birthday);

    cout << "Person(const & Person)... CREATING: ";
    printOn(cout); 
}

Person & operator=(const Person & p) {
        if(&p != this) {
           delete [] name;
           delete emailAddress;
           delete birthday;
           name = new char[strlen(p.name) + 1];
           strcpy (name, p.name);
           emailAddress = new EmailAddress(*p.emailAddress);
           birthday = new Date(*p.birthday);
        }
        return *this;
    }
```